# Anyway to use SSMS to connect to MySql?

Tags: mysql, odbc, ssms

I've grown to love SQL server management studio (ssms), I realise that it is not naturually compatible, however is there a way of connecting to MySQL? Perhaps using an ODBC connection?

I realise there are plenty of MySql admin tools, but it would be great to use SSMS.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx) help? :

> Creating a Linked Server in SSMS for a MySQL database
>
> 1. Download the MySQL ODBC driver from mysql.com
> 2. Install MySQL ODBC driver on Server where SQL Server resides
>      -Double Click Windows Installer file and follow directions.
> 3. Create a DSN using the MySQL ODBC driver Start-> Settings -> Control
>      Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Data
>      Sources (ODBC)
>
>    - Click on the System DSN tab
>    - Click Add
>    - Select the MySQL ODBC Driver
>    - Click Finish On the Login Tab:
>    - Type a descriptive name for your DSN.
>    - Type the server name or IP Address into the Server text box.
>    - Type the username needed to connect to the MySQL database into the user
>        text box.
>    - Type the password needed to connect to the MySQL database into the
>        password text box.
>    - Select the database you'd like to start in. On the Advance Tab: Under
>        Flags 1:
>    - Check Don't Optimize column width.
>    - Check Return Matching Rows
>    - Check Allow Big Results
>    - Check Use Compressed protocol
>    - Check BIGINT columns to INT
>    - Check Safe Under Flags 2:
>    - Check Don't Prompt Upon Connect
>    - Check Ignore # in Table Name Under Flags 3:
>    - Check Return Table Names for SQLDescribeCol
>    - Check Disable Transactions Now Test your DSN by Clicking the Test button
> 4. Create a Linked Server in SSMS for the MySQL database SSMS (SQL Server
>      Management Studio -> Expand Server
>      Objects
>
>    - Right Click Linked Servers -> Select New Linked Server On the General Page:
>    - Linked Server: Type the Name for your Linked Server
>    - Server Type: Select Other Data Source
>    - Provider: Select Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
>    - Product name: Type MySQLDatabase
>    - Data Source: Type the name of the DSN you created On The Security Page
>    - Map a login to the Remote User and provide the Remote Users Password
>    - Click Add under Local server login to remote server login mappings:
>    - Select a Local Login From the drop down box
>    - Type the name of the Remote User
>    - Type the password for the Remote User
> 5. Change the Properties of the Provider MSDASQL Expand Providers ->
>      Right Click MSDASQL -> Select
>      Properties
>
>    - Enable Nested queries
>    - Enable Level zero only (this one's the kicker)
>    - Enable Allow inprocess
>    - Enable Supports 'Like' operator
> 6. Change settings in SQL Server Surface Area Configuration for
>      Features
>
>    - Enable OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE support.
> 7. Change settings in SQL Server Surface Area Configuration for
>      Services and Connections
>
>    - Enable Local and Remote connections via TCP/IP and named pipes
> 8. Stop SQL Server and SQL Server Agent
> 9. Start SQL Server and SQL Server Agent

Comment: This answer seems good however I think it could do with a refresh for later versions of SQL Server

Comment: Beware when joining linked server objects with local DB objects. The performance may suffer.

Comment: MSDASQL is a deprecated technology: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms811968(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Sorry I'm in a different world now, I totally forgot about this question. I'll mark this as the answer from yesteryear! Thanks! ! But +1 the new answer as well as it appears like it may have some new details in.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can.

1. Download MySQL ODBC driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/ and install
2. Go to ODBC Data Source Administrator > User DNS > Add..., and fill all the fields wit the right informations. Then test if the connections works
   [image]
3. Go to ODBC Data Source Administrator > System DNS > Add..., and fill all the fields wit the right informations. Then test if the connections works
   [image]
4. In SSMS go to Server Objects > Linked Servers > New Linked Server...
   [image]
5. Under General set

   - Linked server: (Put what you want, I put the name of the server for simplicity)
   - Provider: **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers**
   - Product name: (Put what you want, I put the name of the server for simplicity, you might want to put MySQL)
   - Data source: **Must have the same name as the System Data Source's Name**
     [image]
6. Under Security select "Be made using this security context" and enter you user and password for remote login to MySQL
   [image]
7. Under Server Options set RPC and RPC Out as True
   [image]
8. Go to Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers > MSDASQL, and enable: Nested queries, Level zero only, Allow inprocess, Supports 'Like' operator
   [image]
9. Restart SQL Server and SQL Server Agent
10. You can now query MySQL from SSMS using this structure:

    select * from OPENQUERY(linked_server_name, 'SELECT * FROM database_name.table_name')

or simply:

```
SELECT * FROM linked_server_name...table_name
```

[image]

Comment: This answer worked with SSMS v18.8 and MySQL ODBC v8.0.27 when the other answer did not (outdated settings).

Comment: This answer assumes you have an existing MS SQL server set up (in order to add a linked server). Not useful if you ONLY want to connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: Well, in that case SSMS cannot connect to MySQL

Comment: This all worked great for me, but is there a way to see the table schemas inside SSMS? The little 'plus' icons in front of the table names are missing.

Comment: @Deckard, I don't remember but probably you cannot. If you need a DB client for different database brand I suggest you https://www.dbvis.com/